# Why am i getting this error 'TypeError: state is not iterable' on react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm trying since a few hours and still getting the same error
**"TypeError: state.codes is not iterable"** when declaring the reducer

*The idea behind my file is to pass a value (code) for ex. '12345' with dispatch into the reducer and be able to update an array _codeData every time when a new dispatch has taken place.*

anyone have any idea?

thanks in advance :),

File1.js

```
function BarcodeScanner() {

  const initialState = {
    code: ''
  };

  const [state, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  function handleScan(code){

    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_CODE',
      payload: {
        code,
      },
    });
  }
```

File2.js

```
const initialState = {
    codes: []
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_CODE') {
        return {
            ...state,
            codes: [...state.codes, action.payload.code],
        };
    }
    return state;
};

export default function ScannerResultTable() {
    
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const [_codeData, setCodeData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCodeData([...state.codes]);
    }, [state.codes]);
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your answer, but i think thats not possible because im using 2 files which interact with each other

Comment: How is the fact you're using two separate files relevant to your question? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: so should i just use the part of the file which is giving me the error?

Comment: Please read the linked pages.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to spread an undefined or null value.
To solve this issue you can use the Logical OR operator.

PS: If the value was always null/undefined, ensure your reducer is working correctly first.

```
const initialState = {
    codes: []
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_CODE') {
        return {
            ...state,
            codes: [(...state?.codes || []), action.payload.code],
        };
    }
    return state;
};

export default function ScannerResultTable() {
    
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const [_codeData, setCodeData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCodeData([(...state?.codes || [])]);
    }, [state.codes]);
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks! -- However, the code as is gives me a type error, so I had to slightly change it to `return { ...state, codes: [...state?.codes || [], action.payload.code] };` removing ( ) from the piece that does the conditional check.